# AngularJS sum of values of selected table elements returns NaN

Tags: angularjs, sum, angularjs-ng-repeat, parseint

I have a counter that tells me how many elements in a repeat table are selected. In the same counter, I want to calculate the total duration of the selected elements.
(Edited according to @JB Nizet, still NaN)

test is a matrix table that contains various info about the test procedure (JSON file).

The table:

```
<table class="setup-table">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 5%"><input type="checkbox" name="test.id" data-ng-model="item.selected" data-ng-change="change(item)"></td>
        <td style="width: 20%;"><a href="#/tests/{{test.id}}" target="_blank"><img data-ng-src="{{test.imageUrl}}" alt="{{test.name}}" class="test-thumb"></a></td>
        <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 5%;"><a href="#/tests/{{test.id}}" target="_blank">{{ test.name }}</a></td>
        <td style="text-align: left;">{{ test.duration }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
You have selected {{selectedCounter}} tests. 
All tests will take  {{selectedDuration}} minutes in total.
```

The counter in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedCounter = 0;
$scope.selectedDuration = 0;
$scope.change = function (item) {
        if (item.selected) {
                $scope.selectedCounter++;
                $scope.selectedDuration += test.duration;
        } else {
                $scope.selectedCounter--;
                $scope.selectedDuration -=  test.duration;
    }};
```

In the view, the number of selected elements is correctly displayed, however the total duration displays 'NaN'. I tried `parseINT($scope.duration,10)` - instead of NaN the selectedDuration remains 0 then.

Comment: Replace `$scope.duration` by `item.duration`. And remove `data-ng-model="duration"`, which makes no sense. Also, what is `test`?

Comment: after doing that, I still receive NaN. I tried it with `parseINT(test.duration, 10)`, where selectedDuration remains 0. 'test' is a matrix table that contains various info about the test procedure (JSON file).

Comment: You haven't answered my question. What is test? Please provide a more complete example. What is the relevant code of the controller? What are you iterating on? It seems the current element is `item`, but then you're also displaying `test`, so it's quite unclear.

Comment: Looks like `$scope.selectedDuration += test.duration;` should be `$scope.selectedDuration += item.duration;` and also the same for the `-=` line (On your **view** you call it `test` but on the **controller** function you call it `item` - I think this is where you're confusing)

Comment: I understand that I should have included this line for more clarity: `<form name="cmpForm2" ng-submit="submitForm()" action="#/setup-step3.php" method="post" data-ng-repeat="test in tests | orderBy:orderProp">`

You were right, I confused item with test - I changed all 'item' to 'test', now it works. Thank you both!